# How to SSH into Android which is a hotspot?

Tags: networking, wifi-hotspot, ssh, remote-access

I am using Wi-Fi hotspot on Android. Can I SSH into it from my laptop which is connected to hotspot? How would I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can any computer connect to a SSH server running on an android phone connected to a wireless mobile network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208972/can-any-computer-connect-to-a-ssh-server-running-on-an-android-phone-connected-t)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run an SSH server on your Android phone. There are apps available, but simple solution is to go for [Termux](https://termux.com). Install app, then  install packages `openssh` and `termux-auth`. Set password and start server:

```
~$ pkg install openssh termux-auth
~$ passwd
~$ sshd
```

If you want to use key authentication instead of password, create key pair on client with `ssh-keygen` and copy the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to phone in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (where Termux's `$HOME` is `/data/data/com.termux/files/home`), and restart server:

```
~$ pkill sshd
~$ sshd
```

Now on client:

```
~$ ssh <Phone_IP> -p 8022
```

No username is required as Termux is the only user which can be logged into. If you want default port (`22`) or a username or multiple user setup, visit the link given below.

**RELATED:**

- [How to run SSH/SFTP server for multiple user logins with password authentication on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209918/218526)
- [How to connect to Android through SSH over 3G/4G public IP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205807/218526)
- [How can I permanently change my hotspot tethering IP address?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213626/218526)

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize termux was different from terminal emulator. Im curious, does it have its own applications etc? Like its own sh etc?

Comment: @Kevin yes it doesn't run Android's `/system/bin/sh` by default, instead its own package `bash`, [modified](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/tree/master/packages/bash) for Android environment.